# Not able to run my CodeceptJS testcases in headless chrome

Tags: automated-tests, google-chrome-headless, codeceptjs

I have CodeceptJS framework setup for my application & tests are runnning smooth. 
But now I want them to run headless chrome. Tried few things mentioned on official site ,but its not working for me.

I try to run my tests with `npx codeceptjs run --verbose`.

My codecept.conf.js file looks like this:

```js
exports.config = {
  tests: './tests/features/**/*_test.js',
  output: './tests/output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      smartwait: 10000,
      waitForTimeout: 10000,
      url: 'https://affinity.sourcefuse.com',
      browser: 'chrome',
      windowSize: 'maximize',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600"]
      }
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js',
    createDatasetPage: 'tests/pages/createDataset.js',
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'dashboard',
  plugins: {
    "allure": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    wdio: {
      enabled: true,
      services: ['selenium-standalone']
    }
  }
}
```

Actual: Chrome is launched & test starts to run.

Expected: I want it to be running on headless chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chromeOptions` need to be wrapped in `desiredCapabilities`, your config should look like this:

```js
exports.config = {
  tests: './tests/features/**/*_test.js',
  output: './tests/output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      smartwait: 10000,
      waitForTimeout: 10000,
      url: 'https://affinity.sourcefuse.com',
      browser: 'chrome',
      windowSize: 'maximize',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js',
    createDatasetPage: 'tests/pages/createDataset.js',
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'dashboard',
  plugins: {
    "allure": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    wdio: {
      enabled: true,
      services: ['selenium-standalone']
    }
  }
}
```

I removed `windowSize` from `args` as it is already set with `windowSize` and added `no-sandbox` instead, as it is recommended for test automation.

Comment: added `no-sandbox` instead, as it is recommended for test automation.

Did not get this part .

Comment: In your initial config you used `--window-size=800,600` as 3rd argument for `chromeOptions`:
1. I suggest to leave this out
2. I suggest to add the `--no-sandbox` arg